# Getting error for while reinflating

Tags: android, android-inflate, viewstub

I am trying to inflate view stub on Button click. It works fine when the button is pressed for the first time, but when I press the button a second time the application crashes.

I am Using the following code

```
 public void display(View V)  //Button Click
    {
         stub=(ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
         inflated=stub.inflate();

    }
```

Can anyone give me some help on this?

Comment: Can't you inflate this view once, keep it in a instance variable and then add it or remove it when you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following check to avoid trying to inflate the [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) several times:

```
if(stub.getParent() != null) {
    inflated = stub.inflate();
}
```

Late answer, but maybe it will help someone :)